# Why is my position absolute not working?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I'm trying to make this component on my website. I would like to have some text on the left a picture on the right side. It should adjust to the text-size and have to be always at the bottom. I thought this is possible with **position: absolute** and **bottom: 0** . But it don't works. It is alway on top over my row and I don't know why.

```css
.b-image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.over-image {
  position: relative;
}

.content-width {
  max-width: 1440px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 24px;
  position: relative;
}

section {
  padding: 48px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content-width">
      <div class="content col-md-6">
        <h1>
          Headline
        </h1>
        <p>
          foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 over-image">
        <img class="b-image" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't see where you're using `position: absolute` – should that be in place of the `position: auto` on `.b-image`?

Comment: @RobinJames Ops, yes you are right. But still dosen't works.

Comment: If you have an element positioned `absolute` inside and element positioned `relative` then the absolute reference is in terms of the element containing it.

Comment: Position: absolute actually takes it out of your DOM. Its size will not influence the rest of your DOM anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using `flex`. Remove `position: absolute` and just give  `display: flex;` to `.content-width` and `align-self: flex-end;` to `.over-image`

```css
.over-image{
    position: relative;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
.content-width {
    max-width: 1440px;
    min-width: 300px;
    margin:    0 auto;
    padding:   0 24px;
    position:  relative;
    display: flex;

}

section {
    padding: 48px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $primary-color-10;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <section>
    <div class="row">
          <div class="content-width">
            <div class="content col-md-6">
                <h1>
                  Headline
                </h1>
                <p>
                foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
                </p>
                <h1>
                  Headline
                </h1>
                <p>
                foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
                </p>
                <h1>
                  Headline
                </h1>
                <p>
                foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 over-image">
              <img class="b-image" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/n1a70o1e/

What you have to do is make two divs. One containing the content, another one containing the image. To make them appear next to each other, give them a width of 49% and 50% (50-50 would be just a little to wide). Use `display: inline-block` to achieve that. It wil make your divs appear next to each other. Then you have to use the `float` property with left or right.

Place your image in a container as you did. The container will resize with its parent, the same parent as your text. Use then `max-height`on the image to resize with the container.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to use bootstrap-grid for that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all styles from .b-image and add this to .over-image

```
.over-image{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the mdn docs

> When position is set to absolute or fixed, the bottom property specifies the distance between the element's bottom edge and the bottom edge of its containing block.

The `containing block` is an element that is relatively positioned. In your case it is the `div.over-image` which doesn't have a specified height and also it is floated because of the bootstrap classes.

So the image bottom edge is aligned with your div bottom edge, hence the illusion of it always overlapping your previous text row . To fix this you can give a height to the `div.over-image` ,which is again dependant on your image dimensions  or you can do

```
.b-image{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 top:0;    }
```

This will cause your top edge of the img element to align with the top edge of your containing div.

P.S: not sure if this is the expected result you wanted, but a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xx5aaz7/1/)